# JavaScript this.form returns unexpected form

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I got some enclosing form and two nested forms. the two nested forms are evaluated with ajax on buttonclick and the external form has a submit-button.

Simplified markup:

```
<form id="form1" action="default.asp">
    //some fields inside a list with unnecessary text
    <input type="text" name="shortdesc"/>
    <form id="deleteform" action="delete.asp">
       //dynamically generated checkboxes
       <input type="checkbox" name="deleter" value="somedocument.txt">somedocument.txt<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="deleter" value="some_otherdocument.doc">some_otherdocument.doc<br>
       <input type="button" onclick="console.log(this.form); ajaxcall('delete.asp', this.form);" />
    </form>
    <form id="addfileform" action="upload.asp">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="console.log(this.form); ajaxcall('upload.asp', this.form);" />
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="send" onclick="dataValidation(form1),"/>
</form>
```

When checking a checkbox and "submitting" the form, console logs outer form, but when choosing a file and "submitting" that, the correct form gets logged.

Can someone shed some light on why and /or how to fix this?

---

For clarification: this is supposed to be some site (**not HTML5**) where you can submit some text-fields to ask the CEO for some changes. I am now supposed to implement a file-append.

The form is handled and created with asp classic (*oh the agony, but well...*) and as I am not really keen to keep the whole form-data throughout **two** redirects(one for the upload and one for the displaying of uploaded files) I had decided to go for AJAX.

FYI: `console.log(document.getElementById('deleteform'))` returns *undefined*

Comment: Having two forms inside a form seems like a grand idea. That's probably the problem right there, and why would you do such a thing (oh the agony) !

Comment: Per the [html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element) you're not allowed to nest forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML forms cannot be nested. What happens here is the browser sees your first `<form id="form1">` tag, but it *ignores* the nested `<form id="deleteform">` tag.

Then it sees the `</form>` and closes the `<form id="form1">`. After that it sees the `<form id="addfileform">` tag and starts a new form, which gets closed by the next `</form>`.

Then there is the last `<input type="submit" value="send">` button, which is parsed as expected but is not inside any form at all.

Finally there is an extra `</form>` at the end which it ignores.

In other words, it's the same as if you'd written:

```
<form id="form1" action="default.asp">
    <input type="checkbox" name="deleter" value="somedocument.txt">somedocument.txt<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="deleter" value="some_otherdocument.doc">some_otherdocument.doc<br>
    <input type="button" onclick="console.log(this.form); ajaxcall('delete.asp', this.form);" />
 </form>
<form id="addfileform" action="upload.asp">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="console.log(this.form); ajaxcall('upload.asp', this.form);" />
</form>
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="dataValidation(form1),"/>
```

One easy way to see when something like this happens is to use the DOM inspector in your browser. This shows the DOM that the browser generated from your HTML code - which will sometimes surprise you! You should also validate your HTML code as others have mentioned.

When you try `console.log(document.getElementById('deleteform'))`, that logs `undefined` because as described above, your `deleteform` never made it into the DOM.

Comment: alright, but then here comes the real fun: i have not changed the markup now (and as you said the "second" form gets ignored. but after the nested form (addfileform) i have the submit-button for form 1. and that works. can you tell me why?

Comment: When you say "submit" button, you really mean just an ordinary button like the other ones shown in your code, correct? In other words it doesn't have type="submit", just type="button". That button works because it's fine to have a button outside a form, and your button behavior is happening from the onclick attribute, not from it being a submit button. Again, load your page and then look at it in the DOM inspector and you will see what happened.

Comment: Look at your page in the DOM inspector. Also, since your HTML code is invalid, different browsers may parse it differently. I'm looking at it in Chrome, and the submit button at the end is outside any form and does nothing when I click it.

Comment: Ah, I see you just added an onclick attribute to your submit button. *That* is why the button works when you click it. You're not depending on it acting as a submit button - and it won't act as a submit button because it is not inside any form at all - instead you have explicitly given it behavior through JavaScript.

Comment: i had the biggest part of it given to me prefixed, the two forms are just the implementation of a new "featured" feature (file-appending), the fun thing was, i needed to move about 500 signs to the right to see the button type(gj developers (doh))

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple forms in a single HTML provided they are pointing to different actions. Nesting of form tags is prohibited

Please go through this W3 specification

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should not use nested forms. If, for any reason, you have the need to use nested forms, perhaps, you should consider changing the architecture of your web-application.

For instance, in your above example, you can replace nested forms with fieldsets, and directly control their respective submit buttons via click event, getting just the necessary info for your ajax calls.